# SVG image in html

Tags: html, css, svg

I have trouble in importing svg image to my html.

this is my code.

[image]

this is what page look like
[image]

and this is directory info[image]

I have another svg it is showing proper results.But this(Layer1) is mine photoshop svg but when I open this by clicking the write image is showing in window's file explorer.

What, I think is image is too large in svg is it a problem? I latter set background of image in photoshop to black color to see if some part of image is visible in chrome. But nothing is visible. Then I set width and height to 400px but same result.
any help please

Comment: `src = "./resources/images/Layer1.svg"` try this?

Comment: Go check what the error console has to say, the circled red x and 1 behind it in your screenshot already indicates that there is an error.

Comment: @ Germa Vinsmoke tried but same results.

Comment: `.html` file is in which directory?

Comment: @ misorude nice point but that are for **Slow network is detected**.

Comment: @Germa Vinsmoke .html file is at Portfolio.I have used server-37258.svg which is showing in my browser.But this one is not.

Comment: Cut and paste the start of your SVG (or upload it somewhere and link to it.  Does [this question help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321984/chrome-not-showing-a-svg-file). Is your SVG self-contained? Or does it [link to a separate image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41195669/images-in-svg-image-tags-not-showing-up-in-chrome-but-displays-locally).  Did you try the [solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737166/chrome-not-rendering-svg-referenced-via-img-tag)?

Comment: @ Paul LeBeau  lotsssss of thanks boss.Your provided links are useful.