# how come my website only fully works on certain browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, firefox

I have made a website and while I was making it I was viewing it in Firefox to review changes as I was going along and it was all fine. I finished making the website to the design I was following and put it on my domain to find that if you view it in chrome or other certain browsers it brakes the website and you can only view it properly on other certain ones like Firefox.

ones its broken on:

- Google Chrome
- Microsoft Edge
- Opera

ones it all works on:

- Firefox
- Internet Explorer

(from my findings)

the website url is https://hily.nl if it helps u can try to view it yourself.

this is what it is meant to look like ( what it currently looks like on Firefox ) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtIJp.jpg

this is what it looks like when its broken ( what it currently looks like on google chrome ):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4wWW.jpg

Answer (score -1):

The first suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321984/chrome-not-showing-a-svg-file) where you have the svg wrapped in `<object>...</object>` and use `data` as opposed to `src` worked when inspecting your site on Chrome and changing attributes.

Comment: thanks, 
have any ideas about how to fix font

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).